# TextView.setText() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, textview, settext

I've got an int `i`

```
int i = 5;
```

then I convert it into String `str`

```
String str = Integer.toString(i);
```

then I try to set String `str` to TextView `tvEx`

```
tvEx.setText(str);
```

And then my program break down. Can you help me?

ExActivity.java ----------

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {return;}
    Log.d(TAG, "1");
    int i = data.getIntExtra("Days", days);
    Log.d(TAG, "2");
    String str = Integer.toString(i);
    Log.d(TAG, "3");
    tvD.setText(str);
    Log.d(TAG, "4");
}
```

Logcat said -----------

> D/Days﹕ 1
>
> D/Days﹕ 2
>
> D/Days﹕ 3

Virtual device -----------

> Sorry, Days has stopped

Comment: Did you initialize your `TextView` ?

Comment: `tvEx.setText(i+"");`   ...  This Will work

Comment: What does "break down" mean exactly? If you have an exception, please post the stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: Show your full code here.Also logcat also.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot Nope)

Comment: have u initialize `tvEx`

Comment: Check by this if(data!=null) { int i = data.getIntExtra("Days", days);}

Comment: @PiyushGupta Intellij IDEA underline `!data` with red.

Comment: @SergaRUS Sorry again check the comment

Comment: @PiyushGupta it fails

Comment: Post your stacktrace here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and specify the exact problem you are having and update the question with an output of your program after it fails.

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null && data.getExtras().containsKey("Days")) {
        int i = data.getExtras().getIntExtra("Days", days);
        TextView tvD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MA_TvDays);
        if (tvD != null) tvD.setText("" + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution to some other problem.

Comment: @laalto it's a solution for shortening the code, but not an answer.

Comment: Please check if your extras has the key: if (extras.containsKey("Days")) {}. Also make sure you initialize tvEx.

Comment: What does the logcat say? Also, I have updated the code. Try now?

Comment: IDEA underline `containsKey` with red. It said: `Cannot resolve metod 'containsKey(java.lang.String)'`

Comment: Whoops - sorry, not using an IDE at the moment. Just writing from the top of my head. I updated the code to get the extras. Try now?

Comment: @martynas My program doesn't fall now, but `tvD` shows "0"

Comment: @martynas I add the log check in your code after `int i ...` and the logs show that `i = 1234`

Comment: @SergaRUS it means tvD is not initialized. Initilize the variable and everything will work :)

Comment: Like this `TextView tvD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MA_TvDays);` @martynas?

Comment: `.getIntExtra` is unserlined with red @martynas

Comment: It said `cannot reslove metod 'getIntExtras' (java.lang.Strings, int)`

Comment: I'VE DONE IT!!! @martynas in your code I've just edit `.getIntExtra("Days", days);` to `.getInt("Days", days);` and everything works now!

Comment: @SergaRUS congratulations! I suggest you use Eclipse - should have taken you like 5 minutes :)